# How to make text dynamically appear between JQueryUI sortables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using JQuery UI sortables for a survey interface. I basically have large ul columns next to one another, representing how you're ranking your choices (prefer less is left, prefer more is right). The choices you're ranking appear as smaller li boxes that are inside the columns, and you can drag them between each of the columns depending on how you want to rank things.

What I want to do is to better signal that choices in the same column are tied. I currently have a little message appear in the body of the page when you drag elements into the same column, but it's easily overlooked so I'm thinking it would be better to put a little "or" between two li elements inside the column itself if they're next to each other in the same column. The problem is I'm terrible at JQuery, JavaScript, HTML and can't think of how to do this. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Here's what my code looks like:

```
<style>
    ...
    .ui-state-highlight { height: 1.5em; line-height: 1.2em; background: rgb(186,228,229); border-color: rgb(195,195,195); }
    .ui-state-default { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 1em; width: 120px; background: rgb(186,228,229); border-color: rgb(127,127,127); text-shadow: none; font-weight: normal; color: black; cursor: move;}
    .vote_col { min-height: 50px; list-style-type: none; margin: 1px; float: left; background: #eee; padding: 5px; width: 142px; text-shadow: -1px -1px white, 1px 1px white, 1px -1px white, -1px 1px white; font-weight: bold;}
    ...
</style>

<script>
    ...
    $( "ul.vote_col" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".vote_col",
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            // if this column already has an li inside of it
            if ($('#' + this.id + ' li').length > 1) {
                // display alert about ties
                document.getElementById('tie-warning').style.display='inline';
            }
        }
    });
    ...
</script>

<body>
    ...
    <ul id=sortable3 rank=3 class= "vote_col"  style="text-align:center;">
            <li class="ui-state-default" choice_id=115>Choice 1</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default" choice_id=114>Choice 2</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default" choice_id=117>Choice 3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id=sortable2 rank=2 class= "vote_col"  style="text-align:center;">&nbsp</ul>
    <ul id=sortable1 rank=1 class= "vote_col"  style="text-align:center;">&nbsp</ul>
    ...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you mean, but at least it's a start. Have a look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f1284pvg/) for a working example.

```
if ($('#' + this.id + ' li').length > 1) {

    current = $(this).children().first();
    $('<span>or</span>').insertAfter(current);

}
```

I've used jQuery to search for the first child of the ul that you're dropping in, and insert "or" as span after it. No matter how much you add, every first element get's a span after it.

Comment: Hmm, this is definitely on the right track! A few issues though -- the "or" spans become their own objects that you can then drag around -- is there some way to make them disappear after you move a choice out that's connected to them? Another issue is, if you drop a choice below another choice (instead of at the top of the column) the "ors" start stacking up next to one another. Is there a way to force the choices you drop to always appear at the top of the column? Thanks for your help!